# Are there a software like Frontpage but generates php codes?

Tags: php

You know that you can build a website with front page without writing a single code! just adding bottons, texts, images, links... and then you get your website! and you can even see the html codes of everything you added!

Now what I need to know is, are there a similar program but works with php codes and not only the html codes! just using bottons, links, images ect.. and then you can see the php codes of what you created!

thanks for the answers.

Comment: Every piece of HTML can be embedded in PHP scripts. Such an editor wouldn't therefore make sense. Apart from that, HTML generators often produce awful code.

Comment: Why do you need PHP in the first place? What features are you trying to implement in your website? Why can't your website be HTML-only? Please tell us, otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: I just want to learn php in that way! creating things manually just like Front page and then see how the codes are created in php.

Comment: A website is made of HTML (and CSS and JavaScript). There is no PHP involved! It only comes into play on the server side (not on the client side).

Comment: PHP's aim is to generate the HTML code. Like Frontpage do. So you're asking for a software that generate programs like Frontpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge such a program does not exist and will probably not ever exist.

PHP runs on the server.
It is used to do server-side stuff like dynamically generate websites.
Where as tools like Frontpage just edit static web pages.
In a sense PHP is a competitor to products like Frontpage.

For example you might use PHP to insert a navigation bar on the top of each on of your pages.  However the navigation bar in PHP has no PHP directly behind it -- it has html behind it.

It may be implemented in a number of ways, as PHP is Turing-complete.

- Possibly the whole overall site is each page slotted into a template written in PHP, that includes the header.
- Possibly each individual page has instructions in it to read a HTML snippet (describing the header) from a file and insert after the  tag.
- Possibly the PHP is more clever, maybe it is generating different HTML for the headers depending on which page it is generating (e.g. the current section may be in bold).

A subsection of a web page won't really have PHP behind it so much as the PHP page (on the server) with have HTML with in it.
Some subsets of uses of PHP might be able to be thought of (/set up) this way,
however you would be limiting yourself to a small subset of the true capacity of PHP.

If you want to learn PHP, then learn PHP, and that is going to involve editing raw text files.
Better yet, consider not learning PHP. It is not fantastic. If you are making something new (rather than learning to support something legacy), consider the plethora of modern web frameworks like Ruby-on-Rails, or Python's Django.

For more information you might like to read [this](http://www.thesitewizard.com/php/wysiwyg-editor.shtml).

Comment: Opinions vary, of course. and I would recommend learning PHP because of it's simplicity, power, maturity and wide support  ("PHP is used by 81.7% of all the websites whose server-side programming language we know" source:  http://w3techs.com/technologies/details/pl-php/all/all).   HOWEVER, if you think that you will ever code both client and server sides, then it might be a good idea to learn JavaScript as NoneJS is now becoming quite popular server side, so you would only have one language to learn.